# My .dat file can't display double number

Tags: java, java-io, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I created my sales.dat with these code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream
            (new FileOutputStream("E:/HOMEWORK/OOP/OOP-java/src/week2/sales.dat"));

    output.writeChars("San Francisco: ");
    output.writeDouble(1123.456);


}
```

And when I opened sales.dat, here it is:

[image]

I wrote another class to read .dat file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("E:/HOMEWORK/OOP/OOP-java/src/week2/sales.dat");
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);

    char[] buffer = new char[4*1024];
    int read = -1;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while( (read = reader.read(buffer)) !=-1){
        builder.append(buffer,0,read);
    }
    System.out.println(builder);


//              

}
```

And the result is :

[image]

So plz help me, the output must be :`" San Francisco: 1123.456 "`

Comment: Don't post picture of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: And there is no NIO in this question. Most of your tags were irrelevant. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: I got it, thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DataInputStream to read.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String name = "...";
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream
                (new FileOutputStream(name));
        output.writeUTF("San Francisco: ");
        output.writeDouble(1123.456);
        output.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String name = "C:/Users/hsivakumar/Downloads/sales.dat";

    DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(name));

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(reader.readUTF());
    builder.append(reader.readDouble());
    reader.close();
    System.out.println(builder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are incorrect. `writeDouble()` writes binary, not readable text. Your reading program should use `readDouble()`, if you can figure out how many chars to read before it. Your output file is poorly designed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a DataInputStream to display the double value :

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException {

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:/tmp/sales.dat"));
        output.writeUTF("San Francisco: ");
        output.writeDouble(1123.456);
        output.close();

        DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:/tmp/sales.dat"));
        String test = String.format("%s%s", reader.readUTF(), reader.readDouble());
        System.out.println(test);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay it seems the problem you are experiencing, maybe because you didn't flush the bytes. 
 Can you please check

```
output.flush();
```

After writing double to the file, and one more thing please try it by putting double value in a Variable first, and then write that variable.

let me know if that fix this problem for you. Cheers

Comment: `DataOutputStream.flush()` does nothing, but he should certainly have *closed* the file.